# Backbone cartesian product with another groupBy

Tags: json, backbone.js, cartesian-product

I have an app in backbone where I use the function to create a cartesian product.

This is the function:

```
    function cartesian(arg) {
            var r = [], max = arg.length - 1;
            function helper(arr, i) {
                for (var j = 0, l = arg[i].length; j < l; j++) {
                    var a = arr.slice(0); // clone arr
                    a.push(arg[i][j]);
                    if (i == max) {
                        r.push(a);
                    } else helper(a, i + 1);
                }
            }
        helper([], 0);
        return r;
    }
```

To call it inside backbone I do this:

```
return cartesian(_.values(this.rooms.groupBy('level')));
```

This is an example of my json fetched by the object rooms:

```
[{"hotelId":"10776","combination":"0|2|0|0|0","n_camere":2,"level":1,"id":"98%7E%7E%7Edouble_1"},
{"hotelId":"10776","combination":"1|0|1|0|0","n_camere":2,"level":1,"id":"99%7E%7E%7Esingle_1"},
{"hotelId":"10776","combination":"1|0|1|0|0","n_camere":2,"level":1,"id":"100%7E%7E%7Etriple_1"},
{"hotelId":"10776","combination":"1|0|0|0|0","n_camere":1,"level":2,"id":"98%7E%7E%7Edouble_2"}]
```

In this mode with cartesian product I have three array grouped by level where every array have the last array because is level2 something like that:

```
{"hotelId":"10776","combination":"0|2|0|0|0","n_camere":2,"level":1,"id":"98%7E%7E%7Edouble_1"},
{"hotelId":"10776","combination":"1|0|0|0|0","n_camere":1,"level":2,"id":"98%7E%7E%7Edouble_2"}

---------------
    {"hotelId":"10776","combination":"1|0|1|0|0","n_camere":2,"level":1,"id":"99%7E%7E%7Esingle_1"},
{"hotelId":"10776","combination":"1|0|0|0|0","n_camere":1,"level":2,"id":"98%7E%7E%7Edouble_2"}

---------------
    {"hotelId":"10776","combination":"1|0|1|0|0","n_camere":2,"level":1,"id":"100%7E%7E%7Etriple_1"},
{"hotelId":"10776","combination":"1|0|0|0|0","n_camere":1,"level":2,"id":"98%7E%7E%7Edouble_2"}
```

.
What I want to implement is to groupby level and combination because in level 1 there is an array with same combination field and my goal lis an array like that:

```
{"hotelId":"10776","combination":"0|2|0|0|0","n_camere":2,"level":1,"id":"98%7E%7E%7Edouble_1"},
    {"hotelId":"10776","combination":"1|0|0|0|0","n_camere":1,"level":2,"id":"98%7E%7E%7Edouble_2"}

    ---------------
        {"hotelId":"10776","combination":"1|0|1|0|0","n_camere":2,"level":1,"id":"99%7E%7E%7Esingle_1"},
{"hotelId":"10776","combination":"1|0|1|0|0","n_camere":2,"level":1,"id":"100%7E%7E%7Etriple_1"},
    {"hotelId":"10776","combination":"1|0|0|0|0","n_camere":1,"level":2,"id":"98%7E%7E%7Edouble_2"}
```

Is possible to obtain this result?

Comment: You can pass a function to [`groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) to build composite grouping keys, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yes but  I want to combine by level, and by combination of same level @muistooshort

Comment: Maybe a better example would help, I'm not sure what you're tying to do and your sample data just looks like line noise to me.

Comment: I have multiple record with some key like name, level and combination. I want to combine each level1 with level2 and level3 with cartesian product, and now is ok. But the problem is when I have in the same level another array with same combination, if there is an array with same external key(hotelid) same level and same combination I have to insert it into the array @muistooshort